# AWS Route 53 redirect between two hosted zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redirect, amazon-route53

How do I redirect if I have a website hosted on example.com hosted zone to anotherexample.com hosted zone. Both are different hosted zone in aws. Now I would want all the traffic that arrives in example.com to anotherexample.com

I see option to redirect between same hosted zone.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `example.com` and `anotherexample.com` are apex domains, you can't use CNAME nor Alias records. Subsequently, I think you could do redirections between the two apex domains with the help of S3 as explained in AWS docs:

- [How can I redirect one domain to another in Route 53?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route-53-redirect-to-another-domain/)
- [How do I redirect an apex domain to its subdomain or any other domain using S3 and Route 53?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already had s3 bucket with same domain. So I choosed to redirect with load balancer adding rule to redirect.